# AWS EC2 IPTables converts source/dest subnet into ec2.internal hostname?

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables, amazon-web-services, hostname

I have a Debian 6.0.7 x64 AWS EC2 server that I'm running a couple QEMU virtual machines on (don't ask.. long story).

I have some IPTables rules to NAT/Forward any traffic (on ports 8080 and 8081) from the AWS server to the VM internal IPs at 192.168.122.150/151 respectively.

When I restore my iptables rules (from an iptables dump), or I manually append an IPTables rule to a chain (FORWARD, for example), the source/destination subnet is getting automatically converted to a .ec2.internal hostname, and I can't seem to figure out why.

For example, the IPTables append command:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 0.0.0.0 -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Nets the following rule (notice the destination subnet was converted):

```
ACCEPT     all  --  ip-192-168-122-0.ec2.internal/24  anywhere
```

I've asked on the EC2 forums [Here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=573376&#573376) but with no response.. anyone have any thoughts on what could be causing this conversion?

The conversion occurs when I import using iptables-restore from a file as well. If I use a non-192.168.x.x subnet, the conversion isn't performed. I'm pretty certain this is breaking a few NAT/FORWARD rules that I have in place, but can't really figure out what's going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNS resolution.  Pass the `-n` option to iptables to disable DNS resolution when listing your rules (ie `iptables -nvL`).  I doubt this is breaking anything.  The DNS resolution is only performed when the rules are displayed, supposedly for your convenience, but I have no idea who actually finds this useful.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I thought that might be the case, and the packets were being blocked elsewhere.. I'd upvote you if I could, but since I'm such a noob I can't :( Cheers!

Comment: Reverse resolution is helpful when trying to identify which host is what.  If you have an application that's restricted to a few dozen IPs in various subnets it helps to see the name rather than the IP.  Granted, I prefer to use a comment to identify the host the rule is for.  :)

Comment: @Gene, ok, it might be occasionally useful, but I wish the defaults would have been the other way around.  No DNS by default, and name resolution with an option.

Comment: I would prefer that as well, but I imagine it's to keep in line with  other utilities that provide reverse resolution by default (e.g. netstat, lsof, arp, traceroute, etc).